# Borgatti Key Player Problem (KPP) in Python

Tags: python, networks, social-network

Has anyone come across any Python implementation of Borgatti's proposed Key Player Problem (KPP) algorithms? I'm interested in solutions using NetworkX and particularly interested in implementations of KPP-NEG.

Here's my implementation of KPP-POS in Python using NetworkX:

```
    # Total number of nodes
    n = len(mod_G.nodes)
    denominator = n * (n - 1)

    # Summation of distance
    sum_of_distance = 0.0

    # Compute shortest path for ALL pairs of nodes
    distance_matrix = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(mod_G)

    for source, destinations in distance_matrix.items():
        for destination, length in destinations.items():
            if not source == destination:
                sum_of_distance += 1 / length

    # Calculate degree of fragmentation
    degree_of_fragmentation = (2 * sum_of_distance) / denominator

    return degree_of_fragmentation
```

Reference: http://www.bebr.ufl.edu/sites/default/files/Borgatti%20-%202006%20-%20Identifying%20sets%20of%20key%20players%20in%20a%20social%20networ.pdf

I'm also interested in Python implementations of Schwartz and Rouselle (2009)'s "network capital" and "intelligence_worth" algorithms too.

Reference: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12117-008-9046-9

Comment: I have found a request for an implementation in igraph but not sure if that's been implemented: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-04/msg00020.html